# How to launch an app via Docker on every Pull Request?

Tags: docker, jenkins, kubernetes, pull-request, rancher

I run Jenkins and my app is dockerized, i.e. when I run the container it exposes port 3000 and I can point my browser there. On every Github PR I would like to deploy that git commit to a running container somewhere and have Jenkins post back to the PR the link where it can be accessed. On any PR updates it gets auto re-deployed and on PR close/resolve it gets torn down.

I have looked at kubernetes and a little rancher, but what's the easiest way to get this going assuming I can only deploy to one box?

Comment: Super easy alternative to this setup would be CircleCi or Travis as they dedicate virtual machines for each build ( for each PR ) and then after build machine is destroyed.

Comment: Jenkins is what we use b/c of its flexibility. We will not be switching.

Comment: I don't really know about jenkins, but if there is a "on PR" script, you could write a script which builds the image from the source repo/branch and launch it on another port (i.e 3001). On a new PR, it checks if the container exists and deletes it before new build...

Comment: yeah Gitlab has review apps which are what I was trying to recreate.

Answer (score 3):

There is a jenkins plugin [github-pullrequest](https://plugins.jenkins.io/github-pullrequest) can resolve your problem.

**Prerequisites:**

1. You have a jenkins server can access by internet if you want trigger your build by a webhook.
2. Your have a github API token to access/admin your git repository, it can be generate by yourself in [settings](https://github.com/settings/tokens).

Please follow the guide [configuration](https://github.com/KostyaSha/github-integration-plugin/blob/master/docs/Configuration.adoc) to setup your jenkins integration with github.

After configuration:

- you can trigger your build by PR events: **opened**/**commit changed**/**closed**, or **comment with specific pattern**.
- you can get a PR status via environment variable **${GITHUB_PR_STATE}**, so you can start or stop a container on specific value.
- you can publish a comment to a PR to tell the address of your web service after you started docker container.

About expose port of cotainer with multi PR, your can just run container with `-p 3000`, it will auto expose a port in a range on the docker host, `docker port <container>` will show the specific port number, so for example:

- `container1` with address `<host>:32667` for `PR1`
- `container2` with address `<host>:35989` for `PR2`

Answer (score 1):

I think the simplest solution to this would be to create two different Jenkins Jobs, one which deploys and the other which nukes it. The trigger for this can be set 2 webhooks in GitHub one for PR create and one for PR resolve.

Answer (score 1):

As Sylvain GIROD pointed out:

With only one box to run the application you need to change the port that is exposed. When a GitHub PR happens you deploy your application (docker run -p newport:containerport). If you are deploying services you change the target port.

Then you send the link with this port back to the user (email?).

Additionally you need some key-value store to remember which pod was created for which users so that you can decide on a new PR whether to destroy the old containers.

I would also suggest giving the services a time to live and regularly cleaning up stale containers/services.